# Почему работает автоматическое преобразование целочисленного типа в тип char Java?

Tags: java

Как всем известно, автоматическое преобразование целочисленного типа в тип `char` как собственно и в `boolean` в Java не поддерживается.

```
char ch = (char) 66; // правильно
char ch = 66;        // по логике неправильно, но это работает
```

Почему автоматическое преобразование во втором случае работает? Если это не автоматическое преобразование, то что это?

Продолжая тему рассмотрим ещё один случай:

```
int i = 66;
char ch = i;        // так не работает
char ch = (char) i; // так работает
```

Исходя из ответа добавлю ещё один пример. Если мы объявим не переменную а константу, то с ней будет так же работать, как и с литералом.

```
final int i = 66;
char ch = i;        // теперь работает
```

Вот теперь мы готовы сделал определенные выводы. Автоматическое преобразование литерала числового типа (`char ch = 66;`) прекрасно работает. А автоматическое приведение числового типа (не литерала) не работает. Как известно из обширных источников интернета, литерал `66` по умолчанию имеет тип `int` - а это числовой тип. Так почему в таком случае происходит автоматическое преобразование в тип `char`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все дело в том, что присваивание целочисленного литерала в переменную типа `char` является **compile-time constant expression** (константой этапа компиляции), которой может быть инициализирована переменная типа `char`:

`char c = 66;`

Здесь имеется одна оговорка. В связи с тем, что `char` представляет из себя [2-байтный тип данных](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)<sup>(*)</sup>, то не любой целочисленный литерал (имеющий тип `int`, размерность которого [составляет 4 байта](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)) может быть использован в качестве валидной для переменной типа `char` константы этапа компиляции:

```
char c1 = 1 << 15; //  < 2^16 compilation ok
char c2 = 1 << 16; // >= 2^16 compilation error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
```

Другими словами, компилятор на этапе компиляции (трансляции java code -> byte code) валидирует размерность, т.е. проверяет конвертируемость значения целочисленного литерала в 2 байта без потерь.

В ситуации же когда в качестве значения переменной типа `char` используется значение переменной типа `int`, то ни о какой константе времени компиляции речи идти быть не может, т.к. значение переменной типа `int`, в общем случае, может изменяться в **runtime** (на этапе исполнения кода), как следствие, не может быть валидировано компилятором на соответствие размерности, т.е. кодируемости значения переменной типа `int` в 2 байта без потерь.

<sup>(*) внутренне данные в рамках типа `char` представлены в кодировке [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).</sup>

Comment: `символы ASCII в кодировке UTF-16 занимают 1 байт` так ведь нет

Comment: @КириллМалышев, и правда, неточность вышла, спасибо за внимательность, исправил :) Что-то меня занесло в сторону `UTF-8` при описании `UTF-16` :(

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ, частично не понятный на моём уровне. Спасибо за редакцию текста вопроса. Очень всё грамотно!

Comment: @Антон, вас все равно смущает то, что это выглядит как [сужение типов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) без явного приведения и не влекущее ошибку компиляции? Получается, что это, в каком смысле, отклонение от общих правил, которое сделали специально для удобства использования.