# Для уточнения типа float используется символ f, как уточнить тип byte?

Tags: java

Для уточнения типа float используется символ f,

```
float value = 1f;
```

Как уточнить тип byte?

Пробовал следующим образом:

```
byte isDelete = (b) ? 1 : 0; // ошибка
byte isDelete = (b) ? 1b : 0b; // ошибка
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с 8ой версии java выделен специальный вид бинарных литералов ([binary literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html)):

```
byte variable1 = 0b00000001;
byte variable2 = 0b11111111;
```

При этом, вы также можете пользоваться шестнадцатеричными летералами:

```
byte variable1 = 0x01;
byte variable2 = 0xFF;
```

Тоже самое относится и к целочисленным литералам (вопреки указанному вами):

```
byte variable1 = -128;
byte variable2 = 127;
```

Очевидно, что в случае превышения максимально допустимого значения в рамках типа byte (256 значений, которые накладываются на следующий целочисленный интервал: `[-128, 127]`), то вы получите ошибку на этапе компиляции:

```
byte variable = 128; // compilation error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

Comment: подскажите а почему это не работает через тринарный оператор в java8? byte isDelete = ((b) ? 1 : 0);

Comment: @FatherOfFiveChildren ТЕРнарный!

Comment: Мне кажется, чел не о том спрашивал

Comment: @FatherOfFiveChildren, вот это уже хороший вопрос! Ответ звучит следующим образом: все дело в том, что в рамках тернарного оператора вы используете переменную, как следствие, выражение не является `compile-time constant expression`. При этом сам тернарный оператор не имеет никакого значения, т.е. вы просто встретили ошибку в контексте его использования, но такая же ошибка может возникнуть и при обычном присваивании. `int i = 1; byte b = i; // compilation error`. Если будет интересно, то вот [в рамках другого вопроса я рассмотрел это подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1292931/200756).

Comment: @m.vokhm, при текущей формулировке вопроса мой ответ, и правда, несколько уходит в сторону. Все дело в том, что когда я отвечал на вопрос, то он выглядел несколько иначе. Можете посмотреть в истории изменений вопроса :)

Answer (score 2):

Любое выражение, если в нем использованы только целые литералы без указания типа или целые подвыражения типа не выше чем `int`, считается выражением типа `int`.

Eсли в целом выражении использованы подвыражения типа `long` (например, целый литерал с постфиксом "L", типа `123L`, или переменная типа `long`, или результат вызова метода с возвращаемым типом `long`), то и всё выражение относится к типу `long`.

Если же в выражении есть литералы или подвыражения типа `float` или типа `double`, то такое выражение относится к типу `double`.

Например,

```
(byte)8 + (byte)2 // тип int
(byte)8 - 2L      // тип long
3.456 * (short)5  // тип double
3.456f / 5.6f     // тип double
```

При вычислении выражения все его операнды перед собственно вычислением преобразуются к типу самого выражения и результат вычислений тоже относится к этому же типу.

Исключение из этого правила -- это присваивание переменной значения константного выражения, т. е. такого, которое состоит только из литералов и констант, и значит может быть вычислено во время компиляции. Тогда присваивание такого типа проходит, но только при условии, что вычисленный результат укладывается в диапазон значений, допустимый для типа той переменной, которой мы его присваиваем. Примеры таких исключений приведены в ответе @StateItPrimitive.

Таким образом, ваше `(b)?1:0;` является выражениями типа `int`, а `(b)?1b:0b` вообще непонятно что, поскольку выражений типа `1b`, `0b` в `Java` не существует. Чтобы полученное значение первого из этих выражений присвоить переменной типа `byte`, надо его явно преобразовать к этому типу:

```
byte result = (byte)( (b)? 1 : 0 );
```

Или иначе можно сделать переменную `b` константой (напр. добавить `final` к ее определению),
и тогда это будет константное выражение и оно тоже будет компилироваться, в соответствии с исключением, описанным в предыдущем абзаце.

PS И кстати, полезно читать сообщения об ошибках. Там есть намёки на то, что именно неладно в вашем коде.